# ¿Como imprimo una ruta en el href de mi etiqueta link?

Tags: javascript, jsp

Lo que quiero realizar es imprimir la ruta del host en el cual me encuentro actualmente.

Primer código

Código Javascript

```
var urlObt;

urlObt = window.location.href;
```

Código JSP

```
String url = "<script>document.write(urlObt)</script>";
```

Impresion en href

Forma 1

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<%=url%>/CSS/index.css">
```

Forma 2

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<%=out.println(url)%>/CSS/index.css">
```

Resultado:

```
 http://localhost:8080/GIBLO/%3Cscript%3Edocument.write(urlObt)%3C/script%3E/CSS/index.css
```

Tambien lo intente directamente desde el JSP

```
out.println(request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.forward.request_uri"));
```

Pero me salia `null`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La función [getRequestURL](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRequestURL%28%29) de JSP te permite obtener la url del cliente que realiza el request, en tu caso puedes hacer algo similiar a esto:

```
<% String url = request.getRequestURL();%>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<%=url%>/CSS/index.css">
```